# javascript safe string

Tags: javascript, string, escaping

when I try to write such JS statement

```
var a = "\images\avatars\";
```

I am getting an error SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

This is definitely because of \ sign, but I need them.
So how can I make this string safe?

PS. escape, encodeURI doesn't help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double them:

```
var a = "\\images\\avatars\\";
```

You'll always need to double a backslash if you're including it in a string literal. You'll have to do something similar to embed the same kind of quotes in a quoted string:

```
var a = 'Don\'t be cruel';
```

The backslash serves as an *escape sequence*.

Answer (score 1):

Escape them:

```
var a = "\\images\\avatars\\";
```

Why do you need backward slashes rather than forward slashes, by the way?

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead.

```
var a = "\\images\\avatars\\";
```